# Filter by dates for map_df function

Tags: r

I have two lines of code that looks like this:

```
US <- tibble(USA = c(......))

Country <- map_df(US$USA, get_country)
```

By using map_df I want to use the function `get_country` to download all available data from first of January 2015 to 1 January to 2018. The dates are in the format 2015-01-01. So I want to find out what to write where ... is to approach the interval.

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to provide you assistance. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Well, > 2015-01-01 and < 2018-01-01. There should be some way approach that intervall between c(....). I'm sorry if I'm not giving enough information.

Comment: This is what I mean by not enough information: We don't know what `USA` looks like. We don't know what `download` means. We don't know what `get_country` is. We don't know what `available data` means..